# I can't get a AST from c source code using cdt plugin eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to get an AST from the source file using the getAST () method. I created a .cproject because I thought if it was the one that was missing, but it still made the same mistake. In this part of the code:

```
ITranslationUnit tu = (ITranslationUnit) CoreModel.getDefault (). Create (iFile);
```

Is returning Null in tu, I believe the error is because of this, but I do not understand why it is returning Null if I am testing with a CDT project with .cproject. I also do not understand IFile, because it is returning a path that I do not know, like this: "L/Users/raiza arteman/runtime-EclipseApplication/testeAST/src/code.c". Below is the class:

```
    public void analyzeFilesInSrc() throws Exception{
        ICProject project = CoreModel.getDefault().getCModel().getCProject(SampleHandler.PROJECT);//project to analyse
        IIndex index = CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().getIndex(project);
        System.out.println("iindex "+index);

        // It gets all C files from the SRC path to analyze.
        this.filesInSrc = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.setSrcFiles(SampleHandler.RUNTIME_WORKSPACE_PATH + SampleHandler.PROJECT + File.separator + "src");

        // For each C file in the SRC folder..
        for (String file : this.filesInSrc){
            String completeFilePath = file.replace(SampleHandler.RUNTIME_WORKSPACE_PATH, "");

            System.out.println(completeFilePath.replace(PROJECT + File.separator + "src" + File.separator, ""));
            this.editDirectives(file);

            IPath iFilePath = new Path(completeFilePath);
            IFile iFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(iFilePath);

            System.out.println("ifile "+iFile);
            System.out.println("Itranslatiotounit "+(ITranslationUnit) CoreModel.getDefault().create(iFile));
            ITranslationUnit tu = (ITranslationUnit) CoreModel.getDefault().create(iFile);

            System.out.println("tu "+tu);
            try {
                // We need a read-lock on the index.
                index.acquireReadLock();
                IASTTranslationUnit ast= tu.getAST(index, ITranslationUnit.AST_PARSE_INACTIVE_CODE);

                this.setTypes(ast);
                this.setMacros(ast);
}
```

is happening this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at analysis.handlers.SampleHandler.analyzeFilesInSrc(SampleHandler.java:249)
    at analysis.handlers.SampleHandler.execute(SampleHandler.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

After I can use this in a CDT project, I will need to parse any c code, even if it is not from the CDT, for this I have seen a suggestion here in the stack of putting a .cproject file in the root in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually creating a `.cproject` file is not the way to go - its format is undocumented and considered an implementation detail. You should let Eclipse create that file, and any other project metadata files, as part of creating a real project.

The creation of the real project can be done manually in the Eclipse UI (`File | New | C++ Project`) or you can automate it using APIs like [`IWorkspaceRoot.getProject()`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspaceRoot.html#getProject-java.lang.String-), [`IProject.create()`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IProject.html#create-org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectDescription-org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor-), and [`CoreModel.create(IProject)`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/cdt/core/model/CoreModel.html#create-IProject-).